# Mousing Over Buttons in Nav Bar Makes Huge Vertical Space in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I'm very new to web design and I made a website for a class project. There is a problem which only seems to happen in Internet Explorer - it works fine in Chrome, Edge, FF etc. When I mouse over my vertical nav buttons, it creates a huge  vertical space and pushes the nav bar and footer waaaaaayyyyyy down with a giant whitespace in the middle - over 10000 pixels of blank space.

This is the Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("nav li").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("normal", 1);
});
$("nav li").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).fadeTo("normal", 0.6);
});

});
```

Here is the HTML for the nav:

```
<nav class="col-md-4">      
    <ul>        
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>      
        <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>     
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>     
        <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>   
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

Can someone tell from this what makes it so out of whack? Thanks!
Here is a link to the site:  [Nail Salon Project Site](http://99mak.com/nailsalon)

Comment: Your nav class as well as your unordered list (ul) is missing a lot of default bootstrap classes and I'm not too sure why you added `col-md-4` to your navbar. I added the missing classes and can't see this vertical space you're talking about. Replicated your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/8dtdjx6q/

Comment: I would recommend you go through a bootstrap tutorial first so you can understand the coding structure as well as coding practices of Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi @AndrewLyndem, thanks for your reply. I was sort of just using bootstrap for the grid/ column layout, not necessarily the styling of the nav bar. I've edited the original post to include a link to the site if it makes more sense to see the whole thing.